# Creating a custom location-centric NER using SpaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

So, I am creating a system where I need to be able to get the location information on restaurant/grocery receipts which have processed through an OCR (so I am working on raw-text) around the world.

I have opted to use SpaCy's NER engine to detect location. However, the existing `en_core_web_sm` model is only good in detecting limited set of locations (`GPE`'s as they're called) like `New York` and `Washington`, etc... which is kind of expected as it has been trained on a dataset involving broadcast news, etc.

Now, I have a dataset where I have information of restaurants located in various cities. The first `column` hosts the information on the complete `address` and the other is the `city`. 
Like,

[image: restaurant address]

I am currently interested in only detecting location up to the level of a city (not further down than that). That is why I am interested in further training my `spaCy` model.

My question is,

Is it okay in using an existing `pre-trained` model (`en_core_web_sm` in my case) which would be fine-tuned when I train it further using the above dataset?

Comment: Please keep the scope of your post limited to *a single question*, see [ask]. Providing a multitude of questions in a single posting greatly decreases your chances of finding a satisfactory answer. Instead, try and break up your individual problems, showcase your attempts on the subproblems, and then work your way from there towards a complete answer.

Comment: Aside from the above issues, are there any limitations as to why you are not trying to solve this with Regex?

Comment: As @dennlinger points out - NLP and NER are not going to work here - Spacy is for analyzing text data in sentences, paragraphs, etc. You will have a very hard time fine tuning Spacy NER for your use case.

Comment: Is the data always that cleanly formatted? If so, don’t use a statistical model. Write a parser using regex or something

Comment: @dennlinger "I need to be able to get the location information on restaurant/grocery receipts which have processed through an OCR (so I am working on raw-text) around the world." I don't think regex would work here. It would be far too much complex for regex to handle as receipts(around the globe) don't have any consistent patterns and I don't want to create a hack.

Comment: @dennlinger I have edited my post btw. So there aren't questions but only a question.

Comment: @AdnanS I am short on time so I wanted something which has already been built. what do you recommend? Are there any existing deep learning/machine learning model(s) which I could use just as it is?

Comment: All the NER models that I know need context - they are not designed for NER on data like your set. If there's a way to segregate your receipts by country, you can segment and process through country specific regex patterns

Comment: Do you think I would be able to find out the location from [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/0a/ce/7c0acecb82f80849b9d4189c5fe94a09.png) receipt and from [this](https://img.etimg.com/photo/59421648/sarcasticrofl.jpg) only using regular expressions? @AdnanS